# Linux static recursive routes not supported?

Tags: linux, networking, static-routes

I'm trying to add some recursive routes. The following idea works fine on say a cisco router, but linux (Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS) is not happy

```
# ip -4 route add 1.1.1.1/32 dev eth4
# ip -4 route add 2.2.2.2/32 via 1.1.1.1
# ip -4 route add 3.3.3.3/32 via 2.2.2.2
RTNETLINK answers: Network is unreachable

# ip route
default via 10.122.197.1 dev eth4  metric 100
1.1.1.1 dev eth4  scope link
2.2.2.2 via 1.1.1.1 dev eth4
```

Comment: Just resolve the recursion manually, and enter the final gateway? Linux sends routed packets directly out, and doesn't treat them as possibly incoming packets and routes them again. *Why* do you think you need recursive routes?

Comment: Yes this can be done manually but my Q is why this cannot be done in linux. Sorry, I can't divulge the why of the project.

Comment: It cannot be done in Linux because that's the way the Linux network stack works - and it makes packet processing more efficient, avoiding an additional check after the routing decision. And if I was implementing the network stack, I wouldn't have included that, either, as I can't see why this should ever be necessary (and you don't want to explain). Is this sufficient as an answer?

Comment: @dirkt The same check could be done once, when adding the route. That's how recursive routes are implemented in e.g. Bird.

Comment: Multiple level route recursion is a fairly standard thing in the router world - but Linux seems to stop at 1 level recursion and 2 levels and beyond fail. I'm not especially buying the answer that this is done for efficiency as like @grawity says it can be done once at route install time into the fib. The rib can still keep track of the multi level recursion. At least that's how it works in routers. So this seems either an intentional design choice to not support this or bug in linux... Bird is new to me - thanks for that info.

Comment: So submit a patch that does the check when inserting the route, either in `ip` or in the kernel. I'm sure you'll hear from the kernel devs if they object to that for some reason ...

Comment: Actually it could be very useful in case of recursive floating static routes with dynamic routing protocols signalling. This construction could be more flexible and specially comparing with external hacks with tracking routes via rtmon or similar ideas (less fragile).

Comment: @dirkt: Turns out the functionality is supposed to be already there and even has an associated flag...but iproute2 quietly ignores the keyword when adding routes.